# Intel XDK: Playing audio that is not in the application folder

Tags: javascript, audio, intel-xdk

I'm making an app with javascript and wrap it with intel xdk. I read [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/493312) the method "requires the sound file to be included within the application file folder".

Is there a way to play a sound with it's full path from the web (like www.example.com/sound.mp3 )? Should I use an audio library for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a special audio library for that, you should be able to do it just as you would in a webpage.  You could create an element in HTML:

```
<audio controls>
    Audio not supported.
    <source src="http://www.example.com/sound.mp3">
</audio>
```

which will give you a play button and controls, with a fallback message.

If you want to create it and control it programmatically, you could do this:

```
sound = new Audio("http://www.example.com/sound.mp3");
```

then when you want to play it do

```
sound.play();
```

I think the audio is downloaded asynchronously, so there might be some issues if you try to play it back before download is complete, but I'm not 100% sure about that.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio for more details.